# Problem with printing unsigned long integers

Tags: c, types, unsigned, unsigned-integer

I have the following simple program that reads in a number given as a string and prints it. It works for small numbers, but when I try to use numbers of size unsigned long, like "18446744073709551615", it does not yield the expected results. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void readNumbers(char* numbers, unsigned long numbers_length, unsigned long* number)
{
    char string[numbers_length + 1];
    strncpy(string, numbers + 0, numbers_length);
    *number = strtoul(string, NULL, 10);
}

int main () {

  unsigned long number;

  char* numbers = "18446744073709551615";
  unsigned long numbers_length = strlen(numbers);
  readNumbers(numbers, numbers_length, &number);
  printf("X = %lu \n", number);            // prints 4294967295

  return 0;
}
```

Edit_1: According to [this site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm) the maximum value of unsigned long is 18446744073709551615.

Edit_2: The following code works on my system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

void readNumbers(char* numbers, int numbers_length, unsigned long long* number)
{
    char string[numbers_length + 1];
    strncpy(string, numbers + 0, numbers_length);
    string[numbers_length] = '\0';
    *number = strtoull(string, NULL, 10);
}


int main () {

  unsigned long long number;

  char* numbers = "18446744073709551615";
  int numbers_length = strlen(numbers);
  readNumbers(numbers, numbers_length, &number);
  printf("X = %llu \n", number);       
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thys do you believe this number fits `unsigned long`?

Comment: `numbers + 0` what is this supposed to achieve?

Comment: what does `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(unsigned long));` say?

Comment: Part of the problem is that `strncpy` doesn't do what you think it does. Try adding `string[numbers_length] = '\0';` after the call to `strncpy`, so that you have a proper null-terminated string for `strtoul` to work with.  (But really, you don't need to be making extra copies of the numbers string, or worrying about its length, at all, I would think.)

Comment: By the way, that tutorialspoint site is **wrong** on this point.

Comment: `18446744073709551615` fits in an `unsigned long` only if `sizeof(unsigned long) >= 8`. Otherwise, the max value it can hold is `4294967295` instead. Check your compiler's `ULONG_MAX` constant. If `sizeof(unsigned long) < 8` but you really need a larger integer, use `unsigned long long` or `unsigned __int64` or `uint64_t` instead, depending on what your compiler supports. Or, use a 3rd party BigInteger library (or write your own) instead.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, the usual advice apples: you need to explicitly tell us what result you expect, and what result you get instead.  Just saying "it does not work" is pretty vague, and leads to unnecessary speculation on our part.

Comment: @SteveSummit: I am sorry, I made an edit.

Comment: In your Edit2: the `strncpy()` last argument:  `numbers_length-1` should be `numbers_length`, otherwise you are missing the last digit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ISO C standard only requires that the data type `unsigned long` is able to represent numbers in the range from `0` to `4,294,967,295`.

On some platforms, it is common for `unsigned long` to be able to represent larger numbers than required by the ISO C standard. For example, on 64-bit Linux, it is common for `unsigned long` to be able to represent numbers up to `18,446,744,073,709,551,615`. But on other platforms, such as 64-bit Microsoft Windows, it is common for `unsigned long` to only be able to represent numbers up to `4,294,967,295`, i.e. the minimum amount required by the ISO C standard.

In contrast to `unsigned long`, the data type `unsigned long long` is guaranteed by the ISO C standard to be able to represent values up to at least `18,446,744,073,709,551,615` on all platforms.

In order to determine the maximum number that is representable in an `unsigned long` on your platform, you can check the value of the macro constant [`ULONG_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits).

Similarly, in order to determine the maximum number that is representable in an `unsigned long long` on your platform, you can check the value of the macro constant `ULLONG_MAX`.

Here is an example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf( "  UINT_MAX: %u\n",   UINT_MAX );
    printf( " ULONG_MAX: %lu\n",  ULONG_MAX );
    printf( "ULLONG_MAX: %llu\n", ULLONG_MAX );
}
```

On 64-bit Microsoft Windows using MS Visual Studio, I get the following output:

```
  UINT_MAX: 4294967295
 ULONG_MAX: 4294967295
ULLONG_MAX: 18446744073709551615
```

On 64-bit Linux, I get the following output:

```
  UINT_MAX: 4294967295
 ULONG_MAX: 18446744073709551615
ULLONG_MAX: 18446744073709551615
```

`UINT_MAX` is the maximum value representable in an `unsigned int`.